# How to determine if there are non-string values in a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use boolean indexing on a Pandas Series in order to determine if there are values in my Series that are not strings.

My approach so far is:

```
contains_non_string = s[type(s) != str].any()
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I correctly determine if there are non-string values in my Series? I am running Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.19.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do something like:

```
contains_non_string = s[s.apply(type) != str].any()
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Can you maybe help me understand why my version was wrong?

Comment: sure, `type(s)` is a series, and `type(s) != str` evaluates to a boolean. it doesn't take the type of every element in the series, it takes the type of the series itself.

Comment: And suddenly he understood. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

another solution:

```
In [22]: s = pd.Series([0,'sss',np.nan,3,'aaa',4])

In [23]: s
Out[23]:
0      0
1    sss
2    NaN
3      3
4    aaa
5      4
dtype: object

In [24]: (s.map(type) != str).any()
Out[24]: True

In [25]: s[s.map(type).ne(str)]
Out[25]:
0      0
2    NaN
3      3
5      4
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's useful to have counts of various types in a Series. The following does exactly the same -

s.apply(type).value_counts()